# Using MAX() in MySQL more efficiently

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all email addresses of customers who have ordered anything with categoryID of 10 but ordered nothing this month. If they've ordered any type of categoryID this month then I don't want to include them.

I am using this query but I don't think it is very efficient, it has been running for ages.

```
SELECT 
    contactEmail, 
    (select max(orderDate) from orders o where o.customerID=orders.customerID) latestOrder 
FROM orders 
    WHERE categoryID='7' 
group by contactEmail
    HAVING latestOrder <= '2014-04-01 00:00:00'
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you need only email addresses or email addresses with `latestOrderDate`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan only really need email address

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET (Your GROUP BY clause is definitely in the wrong place)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the subquery.  You already reference `orders` in your main query.

Something similar to this should work (not tested)

```
SELECT 
    contactEmail, 
    max(orderDate) as latestOrder
FROM orders 
    WHERE categoryID='7' 
group by customerID
    HAVING latestOrder <= '2014-04-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: doesn't latestOrder in this case give me the latest order of a categoryID = 7? I am interested in their latestOrder for any categoryID

Comment: Then remove the WHERE condition.  I only included it here because it was in your original code.

Comment: I can't do that. I only want people who have ordered a categoryID = 7 at some point but nothing since April 1st 2014

Comment: Well you have to restructure your query so that it doesn't nest another query, which is what your original query does.  Your original query is effectively O(n^2).

Comment: You're going to need a JOIN.  Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095158/efficiency-of-joining-subqueries-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT contactEmail
FROM orders 
group by contactEmail
HAVING max(orderDate) <= '2014-04-01 00:00:00' and
       sum(category = '10') > 0;
```

Note that this puts both conditions in the `having` clause and there is no filtering using a `where` clause.